# JPA Specification with subquery

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, criteria, specifications

I have some issues to create a Specification for this case.

I have two entities that are not related with foreign key:

```
Truck
Long id
String name
Long id

Route
Long id
String name
Long truckId (refers to Truck but doesn't have foreign key)
Long planId
```

The recordset could be:

```
Truck
id     name     planId
1      truck1    1
2      truck2    1

Route
id    name       truckId     planId
1     route1     1           1
2     route2     1           1
```

**that means that truck1 has 2 routes but truck2 none**

the result without filter should be all the trucks:

```
1      truck1
2      truck2
```

but I could filter by name and search both truck name and route name.
if I search '2' the result should be:

```
1 truck1 (because of route2)
2 truck2 (because of truck2)
```

but I could also add a search for 'not used in route'
so searching '2' and 'not used' should return:

```
2 truck2 (because of truck'2' and is not used in route)
```

the latest part in sql should be:

```
select id, name
from truck t
where t.plan_id = 1
and t.id not in (select truck_id from route r where r.plan_id = 1);
```

Any ideas?